# std::stoi out of range. Converting from file

Tags: c++, file, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to print the line which is indicated on each line in the file but returns the exception out of range while using std::stoi. The text file has one number on each line from 10 on the first line to 0 at the end. That is why I do not understand why is out of range since it should work with an int, so 32bit.

Here is my code:

```
  if (myfile.is_open()){
    while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
        DirLine = myfile.tellg();
        myfile.seekg(0,0);
        i=0;
        lines = line;
        while (fl){
            j = std::stoi(lines,nullptr,10);
            if (j == i){
                cout << lines <<" - "<<j << '\n';
                myfile.seekg(0,DirLine);
                fl = false;
            }
            getline(myfile,lines);
            i++;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
  } 
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Could you please explain me why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure you're using [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) correctly...

Comment: I am using [this guide](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) and says that should be used `seekg ( offset, direction );`

Comment: ... where `direction` is one of `std::ios::beg`, `std::ios::end`, or `std::ios::cur`.

Comment: I have changed `myfile.seekg(0,0);` to `myfile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);` and `myfile.seekg(0, DirLine);` to `myfile.seekg(DirLine);` and still the same error

Comment: Ok I tested `seekg` in other small program and is working fine like this `myfile.seekg(DirLine,std::ios::beg);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> 1. pass one string parameter stoi(lines);

If it does not work

> 2. put this before stoi : lines.append(" ");

If still error then

```
string::size_type sz;
stoi(lines,sz);
```

I think the problem is, before stoi returns the value. stoi will try to find the position of next char of first number. and assign it to pointer which will be out of bound if there is no character after the number. 
so either you give extra index by appending any character or try to use single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *std::stoul()* function. It parses *unsigned long* values and probably has bigger range (depends on CPU / OS). On Windows, i had problem to parse without index parameter, so at all, it could looks like `std::stoul(line, 0)`. Exists std::stoull for *unsigned long long* either.